# Konversation not working on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, libraries

A few day ago I upgraded to 17.10, today I installed konversation but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
konversation: error while loading shared libraries: libKF5Crash.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

the weird thing is that if I try to run it with sudo, it works, although I get this warning:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
```

Obviously I don't want to run it whit sudo. Any suggestion ?

Alessandro

---

Ubuntu 17.10 - GNOME
Kernel version 4.13.0-16-generic

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I solved the problem. I have located libKF5Crash.so.5

```
locate libKF5Crash.so.5
```

results in:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Crash.so.5
```

I have added the path to /etc/ld.so.conf, the file now looks this way:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

then

```
sudo ldconfig
```

then reboot. And now it works.